# How should I name this method?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I am designing the API for a service that deals with `Job` entities. I need to retrieve jobs given a status. So, I ended up naming my methods like so:

```
List<Job> getJobsByStatus(JobStatus status);
```

A while later I realised that I also need to be able to retrieve jobs which don't belong to a given status. Say, I want to retrieve all **but** the closed jobs.

I have been unable to think of a suitable and intuitive name for this method.

I thought of the below but don't quite find them right.

```
List<Job> getJobsAllButStatus(JobStatus status);
List<Job> getJobsNotStatus(JobStatus status);
```

I can't use a specific status such as closed and christen my method `getAllButClosedJobs` because my method will be a generic one capable of handling any status.

PS: I hope this question belongs to SO though it is not technically *programming*. Otherwise, please feel free to migrate it to a suitable site.

Comment: I tend to feel that this question should be closed as "not constructive" (for any Stack Exchange site). The hint on closing questions as not constructive reads: "*this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion.*"

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add a boolean parameter 'exclude', that would  take care of this purpose. If true, return Jobs that don't belong to that status, and vice-versa. Just a suggestion.

Comment: What's wrong with non-closed as a job status?

Comment: @KurtDuBois Nothing wrong, but if I need to retrieve jobs which are `not closed` or `not live` or `not archived` and so on, I'll have to end up creating many different methods.

Comment: @c05mic Boolean parameters might get rather confusing, as they're not very descriptive on first sight where the method is being invoked.

Comment: Boolean parameters are evil and should be avoided at all cost :) THey basically hide your API inside method implmentations.

Comment: @KurtDuBois: As the first comment says, this question has already solicited opinions. Anyways, I agree with your point about boolean parameters.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call it as long as it makes sense and is well-documented.  Any of those make sense.  I would advise, though, if every call to the method passes the closed status, then perhaps you should just create a `getNonClosedJobs` method that returns everything that's not closed.  Don't say you can't call your method something because it will be generic.  Is it a standard use case that users will query the system for all jobs except ones which have a specific status?  (aside from non-closed jobs, which seems a special case)

Comment: @ErickRobertson Absolutely, that's how my next layer is going to expose methods (`getNonClosedJobs`, `getArchivedJobs` etc). But this API is for a layer that is internal to the one that the outside world can see.

Comment: @adarshr Then the exact name matters even less. Pick something that you think makes sense and document it.

Comment: I think this question is just silly and does not help anyone with any knowledge. How to name a method ? Really ?

Comment: Programming is all about clear communication.  A poorly named method can easily obscure the meaning of otherwise well-written code.

Comment: @mskfisher none of the choices OP offered are poor.  Add documentation and everything's good.

Comment: @ErickRobertson - I agree.  My comment was not directed to the OP - it was originally a comment on alexandrud's comment (which was originally posted as an answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<Job> getJobsExcludingStatus(JobStatus status);
```

or even

```
List<Job> getJobsExcluding(JobStatus status);
```

.......

And for good measure here's why you shouldn't use a boolean parameter. Say you had an interface like this:

```
List<Job> getJobs(JobStatus status, boolean exclude);
```

then imagine code that reads like this:

```
List<Job> jobLIst = getJobs(status, false);
```

How is anyone meant to know how that works? They'd have to dig inside the method to find out that false was a switch for including or excluding or whatever. The `if` statement that would be inside the method implmentation is **hiding** two methods in your API - one that does the true case and the other that does the false case. Typing isn't the bottleneck in software development - it's the thinking.

Comment: I chose to go with `getJobsExcludingStatus`. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for "Typing isn't the bottleneck in software development - it's the thinking."

Comment: +1 Boolean method parameters intended to change its behavior should be strong-typed with enums.

Answer (score 6):

```
List<Job> Jobs.allWith(JobStatus... status);
List<Job> Jobs.allBut(JobStatus... status);
```

Combination of fluent api and varargs

Comment: may be `allWhere(JobStatus jobStatus)` , `allWhereNot(JobStatus jobStatus)`

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Job> getJobsWithoutStatus(JobStatus status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep it simple -

```
List<Job> getJobsBelongTo(JobStatus status)
```

for retreiving all jobs which belong to status.

```
List<Job> getJobsNotBelongTo(JobStatus status)
```

for retreiving all jobs which do not belong to status.

Comment: Maybe `getJobsBelongingTo` and `getJobsNotBelongingTo` for better grammar.

Comment: Agreed, but it may increase the length of the method name and anyways in programming, grammer doesnot matter.

Comment: It can be long, that's not an issue but grammar **does** matter a lot. A misspelled / ungrammatical method immediately brings down the intuitiveness of the API that we create.