# Package name for classes that save and update

Tags: java

I have various class which perform save and update operations of GUI elements, it saves what elements have been added/removed and their new positions.

What is an appropriate package name ?

I considered com.myappname.contentsave but it does'nt 'feel' correct ?

Comment: why you ***FEEL*** it is not correct?

Comment: I would say your question is highly subjective...

Comment: Perhaps, but naming conventions are very important if code is going to be managed by various programmers over time.

Comment: But sometimes the community decides to close [such questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095483/how-should-i-name-this-method).

Comment: @Fahim Parkar because its too specific I think, it should be more generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
com.myappname.persist
```

Comment: OMG, three upvotes?? Thats SO big problem...

Answer (score 0):

In general class and package names should not be verbal. com.myapp.gui.manager could be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could always name a package

```
com.something.guiupdate
```